# Random yes/no generation python

Tags: python-3.x, random

I know that if I want to randomly generate a number I do something like this

```
import random
run = -1
for x in range(10):
    rand = random.randint(1, 30)
```

but how can I get a random generation of yes or no instead of numbers?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it very directly with `choice` from the standard module `random`.

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> answer = choice(['yes', 'no'])
>>> answer
'yes'
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple coin toss would be something like this

```
def coin_toss(p=.5):
    return 'yes' if random.random() < p else 'no'
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to make a list then select one of the attributes like so:

```
import random
l1 = ["yes", "no"]
for x in range(5):
    rand = random.randint(0, 1)
    print(l1[rand])
```

Hope I helped!

-Zeus